# Bind Unloaded Event to a Command - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, binding, command

I'm currently working on an MVVM based WPF Application.

I defined a UserControl like this:

```
        <UserControl x:Class="TestMockUp.Views.DriveStartupViews.VehicleIdentificationViewModel"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                 xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:TestMockUp.ViewModels.DriveStartupViewModels"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:VehicleIdentificationViewModel}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageUnloaded}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageLoaded}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
         ...
    </UserControl>
```

What I'm trying to do is, to hook a command to the Unloaded-Event of the UserControl. I'm not interested if the window or application is closing.

I load the UserControl on demand with a DataTemplate into the Window. I need to register if the Control gets unloaded. I can bind it to an event-handler in the xaml.cs file, but I need to call an Command in my ViewModel.

The Trigger for the loaded event is firing but not for the unloaded event. My guess is, that the `<i:Interaction.Triggers>` is already unloaded before the event fires and therefore it can't be registered ever.

I found some things about AttachedBehaviour, but can't get it to work for Unloaded.

Does anybody know a way, to make this happen without getting any Nuget-Package or ThirdParty Software?

EDIT: The loaded command gets triggered, and the unloaded triggers an event_handler inside the view (if I declare it) but not the command of the `<i:Interaction.Triggers>`

Comment: I'd try first to check if the event is triggered at all.

Comment: @Vlad It triggers if i hook it to the event_handler in the view. The Loaded Event Triggers in my ViewModel too, but not the Unloaded one

Comment: Could you check in the Unloaded event handler if DataContext is still good? I suspect that the DataContext can be already `null` because the control is detached from the parent and doesn't inherit the DataContext any more. This could explain why the bindings stop working.

Comment: Beware! 9 times out of 10 you DON'T need a `User Control`, if this UC is in a `TabControl` then every time tab is out of focus it will call the unloaded event. Highly recommend you don't use events as it is down to the framework when to call them.

Comment: The unloaded event fires when? Think about it. Unloaded means there's no control there. Meaning nothing there to bind to anything. You'd need to handle in the parent and use eventtocommand or the like. Or some other route to achieve whatever purpose you have.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?